# How can I hide a HTML element on a grandfather component after a button on a grandchild component is clicked?

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

I have a grandfather component that shows a message saying that a field on a grandchild component must be updated.

Once the user updates the value and clicks on a button, the HTML element of the grandparent must **immediately** dissapear.

A simplified model of my solution is as follows:

```
<div [hidden]="buttonPressedOnGrandchild">
    <p>You must update the field X</p>
</div>
```

I need to set the value of *buttonPressedOnGrandchild* to true from the grandchild component. Or use another solution to hide the element.

I've found solutions for parent>child and child>parent communication, but not for grandfather and grandchild ones.

Comment: The child->parent->grandparent approach can be one. The other can be using a service with BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up working with a child>parent>grandparent communication via EventEmitter, but for more complex component relationship structures the accepted answer should be the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is a service. Use the service to set the value when the grandchild clicks and let the grandfather subscribe to the value in order to get updated, whenever it changes.

**GrandfatherToGrandChildService**

```
private buttonPressedOnGrandchild: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

// return the Subject as an Observable in order to be able to subscribe to it
public get buttonPressed(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.buttonPressedOnGrandchild.asObservable();
}

// set the current value
public set buttonPressed(value: boolean) {
    this.buttonPressedOnGrandchild.next(value);
}
```

**GrandfatherComponent TS**

```
constructor(private grandfatherToGrandChildService: GrandfatherToGrandChildService){

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    // subscribe to the value and refresh the local variable whenever it changes
    this.grandfatherToGrandChildService.buttonPressed.subscribe( value => {
        this.buttonPressedOnGrandchild = value;
    });
}
```

**GrandChildComponent TS**

```
constructor(private grandfatherToGrandChildService: GrandfatherToGrandChildService){
}

onClick(): void {
    this.grandfatherToGrandChildService.buttonPressed = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up working with a solution of child>parent>grandparent communication, but I believe your solution is the best for more complex component relationship structures.